# inserting a information to all users in single time

Tags: sql, database, plsql

i have more than 10 users in single database that single database is head office,
 include head office all branch offices have same table like  m_farmer.
 if i insert a new farmer information on head office( via head office user).  i need, that farmer information will have to update
 parallel   with head office entry at a time........ help me

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then improve your question.

Comment: Create a trigger which insert records to all the other schemas table once the entry is createdsto the head offiec table.

Comment: user names like
 m_1
 m_2
 m_3
 .
 .
 .
 m_12
 these all users having a same m_farmer table.
 m_1 is a head office and it has a server and database, 
 and no other branches wont have any servers 
 they all are connecting this m_1 server via web browser,now
 if they(may be m_3) insert one farmer information to m_farmer(master farmer table) ,
 that information of farmer should access with all other 10 branches

Comment: If there's only one database, in the head office, exactly what is you want to update?

Comment: Not sure what your actual requirement is but you can create a public synonym for the master table and grant access to other users to access that table. No point creating multiple copies of the same table in a database